# Hypothetical [tips] questions

Tags: discussion

I propose that we create a [tips](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) tag so people can get general tips on a game or puzzle.

I would greatly appreciate any community input on changing or adding/removing requirements.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're putting the cart before the horse here. You should be asking whether this type of question is on-topic. If so, we can discuss whether we want a tag for it, if not the point is moot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please, no. Not “one X per answer”.

An answer that discusses multiple tips and explains how they relate to each other, when each one is applicable, and how to choose between them, is superior to a collection of unrelated tips.

The ranking of scores on such answers reflects primarily how old they are. It rarely ends up reflecting how useful the tip is.

“Don't edit” runs directly against the whole purpose of Stack Exchange. If you can improve someone's answer, do edit it! (It's also contradictory to one-tip-per-answer — if you present the information with one tip per answer and you want to improve someone's tip, you should edit their answer!)

This isn't the first time “one X per answer” has come up on Stack Exchange, and every time, it's only lead to poorer answers. We should encourage comprehensive answers.